# What method is used to capture entire page screenshot using Google chrome?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-rc

I am using selenium RC to automate my project. I have executed the script using firefox. I have used selenium.CaptureEntirePageScreenshot() to take screen shot using firefox. But this method doesn't work with Google chrome. Which method should I use to capture entire page screen shot for Google chrome?

Comment: Can I ask why you are still using Selenium RC? It's deprecated. So you will only find hacks as workarounds, not official solutions.

Comment: So what's the alternative? I have heard about Selenium Web Driver. But I am not much aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
selenium.captureScreenshot("C:/filename.png")
```

Comment: I tried using the above method. It takes screenshot and does not give any error. But the screenshot is of any page that gets displayed on my desktop. Not the actual screenshot that I need.

Comment: you need to keep the browser in which your test is running maximised, please try this..

Comment: I have tried keeping the application maximised. But the problem is that in my application the output of few screens is seen at the end of the page. I need the screenshot of the output that is displayed on page. For that every time i run the test, i have to scroll the page at the end to capture the output that is displayed below(if i am using selenium.capturescreenshot()). I want the screenshot of the complete page, the way it is seen using selenium.captureentirepagescreenshot(). Please let me know if any suggestions.